# How to set the starting position of the slider?

Tags: android, user-interface, slider, custom-controls

Please tell me how to set the starting position of the slider, I've been searching for an hour and can not find it :(

https://github.com/channguyen/range-slider-view

Comment: starting position means, you want to start the slider from between the an specific point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this **setInitialIndex(int value)**

```
 rsv_large= (RangeSliderView) findViewById(R.id.rsv_large);
 rsv_large.setInitialIndex(2);
```